# Get twitter button count for many urls with one API call

Tags: api, twitter

I found how to get share count of one url:

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://example.com

since this is undocumented feature, official documentations says nothing about it,
But is it possible to get count of many urls with one API call?

Answer (score 1):

This method, as far as I know, only returns results for one URL, so you'll need to call `count` for each URL. I've never seen a call to `count` that has multiple URLs, and I think that makes sense, because the call is usually tied to only one tweet button -- there's never a multi-URL tweet button.

I would, however, discourage using this API until Twitter opens it explictly, since you run the risk of having your app suddenly stop working, or worse, getting your IP banned.